# What keeps the Daleks from conquering the universe?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

The time war was supposed to have destroyed Daleks and Time Lords alike.

However this has been somewhat retconned in the last seasons.

As it stands the Time Lords are locked away out of universe while the Daleks have been able to re-establish their numbers and the canon states pretty clearly that only the Time Lords were a match for them.

So, what is keeping them from killing every other lifeform in the universe?

Comment: Not 'what?' but 'who?' - doctor who ;)

Comment: That old dude who travels in a police box :p

Comment: it would explain the dr's sudden age jump from 1000-ish to 2000-ish if he was spending the extra 1000 teaching everyone to stick chewing gum on their eyeballs (the darleks eyeballs that is)

Comment: Every time they try to conquer the universe, the Doctor stops them. That is the very essence and root of their antipathy toward him.

Comment: Little known fact, it's [jelly babies](https://youtu.be/mfisgGuuUD8). Daleks are diabetic. Really messes with their insulin levels. I believe [Jammie dodgers](https://youtu.be/PH-P4nTkTpQ) are also effective.

Comment: “As it stands the Time Lords are locked away out of universe” — not quite. They came back, then promptly went to hide at the end of the universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Time Lord's have taken specific actions to prevent the daleks from conquering the universe.  At the beginning of "Genesis of the Daleks," the Doctor and Sarah Jane are diverted from their destination and sent to Skaro at the time of the daleks' creation.  A Time Lord representative informs them that the Time Lord's have discovered that the daleks do conquer the universe in the far future.  To prevent this, the Doctor (the most experienced dalek fighter in the spacetime continuum) had been sent to Skaro to interfere with the daleks' creation.  Although he does not manage to stop the daleks entirely, the Doctor does weaken them, protecting the time stream, at least for a while.

The Time Lord's devotion to keeping the daleks from dominating the cosmos is also demonstrated in the new series.  The prevent dalek hegemony, the Time Lord's fought the daleks in the Time Warner, attempting to permanently seal both races' doom.

Comment: ah, the last great Time Warner :)

Comment: I believe the government prevented the merger of the Daleks and Time Warner.

Answer (score 0):

Terry Nation made several attempts to market the Daleks outside of Dr Who, but these were unsuccessful. However, they did appear without Dr Who in comics (TV 21, The Dalek Chronicles) as well as several annuals. They also appeared at least in one play without the Doctor, "The Curse of the Daleks". As well, there was a Big Finish story "Daleks The Destroyers" that involved the Daleks and the Space Security Service.  This was the original spin-off that Terry Nation was trying to promote (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0jWZYrXTXc)).

More recently, the Daleks have appeared in The Big Finish Productions "Dalek Empire", where the Doctor I think only appears very infrequently (I can only think of one story).

Finally, the Daleks have met races like the Mechanoids and the Movellans. While the Mechanoids did not seem to offer much of a threat in the classic series, in the TV 21 they presented more of a threat.

Originally one of the reasons the Daleks failed to conquer the universe was stairs! But the most probable reason is, if the Daleks did conquer the universe, there wouldn't be much else to write.
[image]